# XCode automatically creating repository in Home folder

Tags: xcode, git

Every time I open a certain project in Xcode which is under git version control, Xcode adds another repository to the organiser with the name of my user account, located in my user directory.

When trying to commit changes using Xcode, this repository shows up and shows changes from all the Xcode projects I have in my user directory. If I remove the repository from the organiser, I cannot commit any changes or pull from the remote git repository (nothing happens when these menu options are selected). However if I quit Xcode and open the project again, the repository is back.

Would appreciate it if anyone has any idea what's going on here.

Comment: OK I'm still none the wiser as to why Xcode was adding this automatically or as to how it was created in the first place, but somehow my home directory had a .git folder inside. I've removed this and everything seems fine now...